# How to convert my custom ERC20 token to BEP20?

Tags: remix, erc-20, cross-chain, create, wrapped-tokens

I have my custom token on the Ethereum network and I want to send part of the tokens to the binance smart chain. That is, issue a wrapped token.For example:

https://etherscan.io/token/0x1f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984
https://bscscan.com/token/0xbf5140a22578168fd562dccf235e5d43a02ce9b1

or

https://etherscan.io/token/0xa31b1767e09f842ecfd4bc471fe44f830e3891aa
https://bscscan.com/token/0xe64f5cb844946c1f102bd25bbd87a5ab4ae89fbe

Perhaps burgerswap will help me, but I tried to create a cross-chain asset and the transaction was canceled